# Skip corrupted page in pdf using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, pdf

I have a corrupted .pdf file with me. When I try to open the file it throws exception on the

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);
```

line if there is any error on a page.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Full code:

```
public string ReadFile(string Filename)
{
    string fileName = Server.MapPath(@"PDFFiles//" + Filename);

    string pdfText = string.Empty;
    if (File.Exists(fileName1))
    {
        try
        {
            // Exception on this line
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);

            for (int i = 1; i <= pdfreader.NumberOfPages; i++)
            {
                ITextExtractionStrategy itextextStrat = new pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Filename);
                String extractText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, itextextStrat);

                extractText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(extractText)));
                pdfText = pdfText + extractText;
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        catch(Execption e)
        {
        }
    }

    return pdfText;
}
```

But I need to loop through the file without an exception. If there is any error on a particular page, I have to skip it and move to the next page. It should not throw exception. How to achieve this?

Comment: Not the first the second.  Why are you new and closing in the loop?  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Filename);

Comment: Your opening two different PDF files, one referenced by fileName, and the other by FileName.  But more importantly are you certain that the PdfReader class can handled the corrupt PDF?  Adobe Reader might be able to skip the page, but that doesn't mean everything can.  Plus are you sure that the .GetTextFromPage handles PDF's with images and other formatting?

Comment: Oh and you've got a trailing 1 on the if(File.Exists(fileName1)) line.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a `try-catch` block should be enough for you. Simply wrap the problematic code to catch any exceptions and the loop will continue no matter what.

Comment: But the for loop breaks. I need to continue the for loop.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar, uhm, that's why I've suggested a `try-catch` block. What's the hard part for you to understand? You've never tried to catch an exception?

Comment: Now i have edited the code. But the for loop breaks after an exception is thrown in the instance of pdfreader.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar, you must insert your try-catch block `inside your loop`, or else it breaks as you've already found out ;)

Comment: But the exception is thrown in the **PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);** itself.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar, in that case it never makes to the loop in the first place, so there's no loop to continue. If you can't even create your PdfReader object, there's no way to "fix" this...Corrupted files are called corrupted for a reason. Not sure if there's a free library for fixing broken pdf files..